# C# Web API - Getting an error message when I don't pass all of the query string parameters

Tags: c#, url, query-string, webapi

I have this controller that fetches data based on date filters. If both dates are null then the service will assign default values.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetOrdersByUserId")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetOrdersByUserId([FromUri] DateTime? startDate = null, [FromUri]  DateTime? endDate = null)
        {
                try
                {
                    ResponseViewModel<object> resp = new ResponseViewModel<object>();
                    OrderService service = new OrderService();
                    resp.data = service.GetOrdersByUserId(startDate, endDate);
                    resp.status.code = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    return Ok(resp);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WebApiExceptionHandler.Handle(Request, ref ex);
                    throw;
                }
        }
```

The following case runs fine.

.../api/v1/Retailer/GetOrdersByUserId?startDate=2020-02-04&endDate=2020-02-05

However I get this error message "**The argument cannot be null**" when I remove either or both parameters.
.../api/v1/Retailer/GetOrdersByUserId

.../api/v1/Retailer/GetOrdersByUserId?startDate=2020-02-04

.../api/v1/Retailer/GetOrdersByUserId?endDate=2020-02-05

I would be grateful, if you can help me solve this issue.

Comment: Try `[FromQuery]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the error is on line **resp.data = service.GetOrdersByUserId(startDate, endDate);** Does your OrderService.GetOrdersByuserId method allow optional parameters as well? If not, it is expecting two parameters, start and end date, to be there.

What you could do is check to see if the API parameters are null and set the bounds if they are. Ideally, you'd change null from the constructor to the value you want, but I don't believe you can for DateTime. For example:

```cs
if (startDate == null) {
    startDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
}
if (endDate == null) {
    endDate = new DateTime(9999, 1, 1);
}
//Can be shorter with ternary operators
//Variable =    condition     ?           true           :   false
startDate = startDate == null ? new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) : startDate;
endDate = startDate == null ? new DateTime(9999, 1, 1) : startDate;

//Your existing code
try {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the optional arguments of startDate and endDate is useless here. You can remove it.
I think the fromURI attribute is also useless here. DateTime is not a complex type. The attribute is used for the complex type.
Just  try

```
public IHttpActionResult GetOrdersByUserId(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
```